# How can I initialize an empty vector in JavaScript, but in a way that it has X positions?

Tags: javascript

How can I initialize an empty vector in JavaScript, but in a way that it has X positions? For this I had to make a loop and set some values ​​for the positions of the vector. I want a more correct way to do it.

```
let values: [],

for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
   this.state.values[i] = '';
 }
```

Comment: `Array.from({ length: x }, e => "");`, but i dont see this as "more correct", maybe a different approach. Another way would be `Array(x).fill("");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
new Array(x);
```

To produce an array with x empty values.

You can then map it by expanding the array:

```
[...new Array(x)].map(_=>/*your  code*/);
```

Comment: I've tried to do it like this, but this way if I make a "map", it doesn't go x times.

Comment: @wesif, right, this happens because the array constructor doesn't actually "fill" the indexes with `undefined`, the array constructor just initializes the length, not the index properties.

Comment: The indexes can be populated via expansion

Answer (score 0):

Here are some short and elegant ways on top of my mind:

```
Array.from(Array(size), () => value)
Array.from({ length: size }, () => value)
Array(arraySize).fill(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix the following Array and create a static `filledArray` function on the `Array` object.

- `new Array(size)`
- `Array.prototype.fill`
- `Array.from`

```js
if (Array.filledArray === undefined) {
  Array.filledArray = function(size, defaultValue, start, end) {
    return (arr => Array.prototype.fill.apply(arr, Array.from(arguments).slice(1)))(new Array(size));
  }
}

let values = Array.filledArray(7, 'foobar');

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important;}
```